# How to fetch and parse JSON from an ASMX Webservice using iOS SDK?

Tags: c#, ios, json, web-services, asmx

I have a ASMX - Web Service and wanted to request a result as JSON. Therefore I used Fiddler to send a POST-Request.

Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> AllProjects()
{
   List<ProjectData> pList = m_linqHelper.GetProjects(string.Empty).ToList();
   List<string> ProjectNames = pList.Select(p => p.ProjectName).ToList();
   return ProjectNames;
}
```

Fiddler POST-Request:

```
POST http://localhost:52225/MyWebService.asmx/AllProjects HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:52225
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

As the result I got a string like:

```
{"d":["My_Project"]}
```

What bothers me is the **"d":**. How can I parse such a request using the iOS SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use ASMX webserices too.
For my requests I have implemented the [AFNeworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library available on GitHub to call Webservice.

You can find help on the GitHub page.
Then, the webservice give me a JSON result. So I convert it like that :

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
```

Where responseObject is the result of AFNetworking request.

Comment: Aren't there any easier solutions? Normally the data is grouped like {ID : Value }. But how does it work when I only return a string? Like I mentioned above, all I get is: {"d":["My_Project"]}